# sendMifareCommand() API randomly returns various errors

Tags: ios, mifare, core-nfc

To read from an Mifare Ultralight tag (NTAG I2C Plus), I'm using NFCMifareTag.sendMifareCommand method. It works most of the times, but I randomly get errors of type Tag Response Error / Tag No Response / Tag Connection Lost / Stack error. I haven't been able to find a pattern or root cause of these errors, and there is no help available on Apple's documentation for these errors.

Here's the code snippet (using Xamarin)

```
            miFareTag.SendMiFareCommand(tagCommand, completionHandler: (nsdataObj, error1) =>
            {
                if ((error1 == null) && (nsdataObj != null))
                {
                    readSuccess = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    readSuccess = false;
// here error1 prints 'Tag response error' or 'Tag no response' or 'Tag connection lost' or 'Stack error'
                }
            });
```

One thing I'm sure about is the errors are not related to phone's position against the NFC tag. No matter how close I hold the phone, the errors do come up randomly. I've also observed these errors to occur more frequently on iPhone 13 models than the older ones.

Has anyone observed these errors and is aware about way to avoid / handle those?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to send commands the miFare tag and I get absurd response command like that 911C, 919D..., can u help me for this problem?

Comment: These could be NAK error codes being sent from the NFC tag you're using. Have you referred data sheet of the NFC tag? It could be describing  these NAK codes, if that's what they are.

Comment: I see the same kind of errors.  Sometimes it works fine transferring data for 20-40 seconds, sometimes just 3-5s before one of those errors happens.  No clue yet.

Comment: Hi @zeuschyant8. I'm in very similar situation. Did you solve? Or did you find the cause? Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Still no solution. I had raised this on Apple's Feedback Assistant Tool. Here's the link: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/10012673 They asked me for some background debug logs. When they analyzed, they responded that data frames seem to be dropping at RF communication level, reason for that not yet found out. I'm following it up there. I would recommend everyone facing this issue to report similar issues on the feedback assitant.